# Minimizing a quadratic form with orthogonality constraints

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Suppose $A$ is an $n$-by-$n$ symmetric matrix, and I want to find $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ that maximize $x_{1}^{T} A x_{1} + x_{2}^{T} A x_{2}$ subject to the constraint that $x_{i}^{T} x_{j} = \delta_{ij}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta function (in other words, $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ must be orthogonal unit vectors). I know that the answer to this problem is to let $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ be orthonormal eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to the two largest eigenvalues. I have found this result cited in a couple of places on the internet, but cannot seem to find a proof. I'm also not sure what this result is called, although [some people call it an extremal trace problem](http://stanford.edu/class/ee263/notes/low_rank_approx.pdf). However, I cannot find other source that use the phrase "extremal trace problem."

So, what are these problems called? And how can I prove that the solution is given by the eigenvectors corresponding to the largest eigenvalues?

Comment: This may be of help, page 3: http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/PDF/umsi-2009-31.pdf

Comment: And this one too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem